# Linq variable inside select

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a following query

```
 return _context.Table1
                    .Where(x => x.ContactId == contactKey.Id)                       
                    .Include(x => x.Table2)                        
                    .Include(x => x.Table3.Table4)
                    .Select(a =>
                        new MyReadModel
                        {                               
                            PriorityAssignment = true,
                            LastContactedDate = (a.Table3.Table4 != null && a.Table3.Table4.FirstOrDefault(h => 
                            h.Id == a.Table2.FkId
                            ) != null ?
                            a.Table3.Table4.FirstOrDefault(h => && h.Id == a.Table2.FkId
                            ).LastContactedDatetime : default
                            )
                        }
                     )
                    .ToListAsync();
```

What i wants is to simplify LastContactedDate assignment with in select. I think we can assign

```
a.Table3.Table4.FirstOrDefault(h => 
                                h.Id == a.Table2.FkId
                                )
```

to some variable but can't able to do it
can someone identify what is needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With EF Core you don't have to check for null, LINQ Translator do not execute your code, but uses it for translation to the SQL. Also Includes is not needed if you do not retrieve whole objects.

```cs
return await _context.Table1
    .Where(x => x.ContactId == contactKey.Id)                       
    .Select(a => new MyReadModel
    {                               
        PriorityAssignment = true,
        LastContactedDate = (DateTime?)a.Table3.Table4.Where(h => h.Id == a.Table2.FkId)
            .OrderByDescending(h => LastContactedDatetime)
            .Select(h => LastContactedDatetime)
            .FirstOrDefault()
    }).ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use it like this example

```
    List<string> someList= new List<string>();
    someList= someList.Select(x =>
    {
        var newVariable= "newVariable";
        return newVariable;
}).ToList();
```

in your case

```
 return _context.Table1
                .Where(x => x.ContactId == contactKey.Id)
                .Include(x => x.Table2)
                .Include(x => x.Table3.Table4)
                .Select(a => {
                    Table4 newVariable = null;
                    if(a.Table3.Table4 != null)
                        newVariable = a.Table3.Table4.FirstOrDefault(h => h.Id == a.Table2.FkId;
                    var result = new MyReadModel
                    {
                        PriorityAssignment = true,
                        LastContactedDate = (newVariable != null ? newVariable.LastContactedDatetime : default
                        )
                    };
                }
                 ) .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: getting error may be as not returning result. i have to use the asycnList one